# Calories Burnt whilst excercising

Tags: exercise, calories

What is the best way to calculate calories burnt whilst exercising, mainly running without the use of a website or app. I am looking for a formula, it only needs to be an estimate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form, I would say very roughly 100 caloies per mile run